# Laravel - Search Filter in Relationship Problem in Fetching Data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, relationship

Trying to get data from a table "mobiles", and its related entry in Stock. While my search keyword is mobile model, see Mobiles table below

[image]

and related table "Stock" is below also

[image]

Mobile Model is:

```php
class Mobile extends Model
{
    public function company(){
        return $this->hasMany(Company::class);
    }
    public function stocks(){
        return $this->hasMany(Stock::class);
    }
}
```

Stock Model is:

```php
class Stock extends Model
{
    public function company(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'company_id');
    }
    public function mobiles(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Mobile::class, 'model_id');
    }
}
```

index method of Stock is:

```php
public function index(Request $request)
    {
      $request->session()->put('search', $request
        ->has('search') ? $request->get('search') : ($request->session()
          ->has('search') ? $request->session()->get('search') : ''));

      $request->session()->put('field', $request
        ->has('field') ? $request->get('field') : ($request->session()
          ->has('field') ? $request->session()->get('field') : 'model_id'));

      $request->session()->put('sort', $request
        ->has('sort') ? $request->get('sort') : ($request->session()
          ->has('sort') ? $request->session()->get('sort') : 'asc'));

      $stocks = new Stock();

      $stocks = $stocks->where('model_id', 'like', '%' . $request->session()->get('search') . '%')
      ->orderBy($request->session()->get('field'), $request->session()->get('sort'))
      ->paginate(5);

      if ($request->ajax()) {
        return view('pages.stock.index_stock', compact('stocks'));
      } else {
        return view('pages.stock.ajax', compact('stocks'));
      }      
    }
```

Problem is that i can search using model id because search filter is set on "stock" table, column "model_id". how can i search by writing mobile model name that is existing in table "mobiles", after searching model it should display complete info related to searched mobile model.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are the `mobiles` and `stocks` tables related? I see no `mobile_id` field? And based on your schema, the relationship between a `Mobile` and a `Company`, should be `belongsTo` not `hasMany`.

Comment: i set a foreign key inside "model_id" in model "mobiles".

Comment: So are you trying to get a list of stock based on the name of a mobile phone?

Comment: yes. you are on target

Comment: And what fields are you sorting by? Just fields on the `Stock` model?

Comment: by "created_at"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181251/discussion-between-hassan-raza-and-fubar).